# Mysql Cluster Ndb Restore Foreign key constraint violated

Tags: mysql-cluster, ndbcluster

I am trying to restore mysql cluster backup on slave cluster.

When i run ndb_restore command it gives me following error:

```
$ /usr/local/mysql/bin/ndb_restore -n 6 -b 15 -r ./6

Opening file './6/BACKUP-15.6.log'
File size 1210464 bytes
execute failed: 255: Foreign key constraint violated: No parent row found

NDBT_ProgramExit: 1 - Failed
```

How can i skip foreign key errors ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With any more complex data it is almost impossible to restore data in MySQL Cluster in one step. Usually one needs two steps:

```
ndb_restore <other_options> --disable-indexes

ndb_restore <other_options> --rebuild-indexes
```

First step has to be run on all nodes of the cluster. Second step though - just on one node which will rebuild all the indexes.

For foreign keys you can try to split first step into two:

```
ndb_restore <other_options> --restore_meta

ndb_restore <other_options> --restore_data --disable-indexes
```

`--restore_meta` has to be run on one node. `--restore_data` on all the nodes in cluster.

Comment: Edited the answer. Have not tried suggested way myself though.

Comment: Can you try to drop foreign key constraint after --restore_meta and recreate after restoring the data?

Comment: Actually disabling indexes while restoring data works. Probably i made a mistake at my first try. I could restore data successfuly following these steps. Thanks for reply :)